# Sockets receive hangs

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sockets, screen-scraping

I am trying to download, search page of bing, and ask using sockets, i have decided to use sockets, instead of webclient.

The **socket.Receive();** hangs after few loops in case of bing, yahoo, google but works for ask. for google loop will receive for 4 - 5 times, then freeze on the call.

I am not able to figure out why?

```
public string Get(string url)
{
    Uri requestedUri = new Uri(url);
    string fulladdress = requestedUri.Host;
    IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(fulladdress);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP))
        {
            socket.Connect(entry.AddressList[0], 80);

            NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(socket);

            string part_request = string.Empty;
            string build_request = string.Empty;
            if (jar.Count != 0)
            {
                part_request = "GET {0} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {1} \r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\nCookie: {2}\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
                build_request = string.Format(part_request, requestedUri.PathAndQuery, requestedUri.Host, GetCookies(requestedUri));
            }
            else
            {
                part_request = "GET {0} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {1} \r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
                build_request = string.Format(part_request, requestedUri.PathAndQuery, requestedUri.Host);
            }

            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(build_request);
            socket.Send(data, data.Length, 0);

            byte[] bytesReceived = new byte[102400];
            int bytes = 0;

            do
            {
                bytes = socket.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
                sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes));
            }
            while (bytes > 0);

            List<String> CookieHeaders = new List<string>();
            foreach (string header in sb.ToString().Split("\n\r".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                if (header.StartsWith("Set-Cookie"))
                {
                    CookieHeaders.Add(header.Replace("Set-Cookie: ", ""));
                }
            }

            this.AddCookies(CookieHeaders, requestedUri);

            socket.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string errorMessage = ex.Message;
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}

CookieContainer jar = new CookieContainer();

public string GetCookies(Uri _uri)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    CookieCollection collection = jar.GetCookies(_uri);

    if (collection.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (Cookie item in collection)
        {
            sb.Append(item.Name + "=" + item.Value + ";");
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I would guess that the services (Google etc) are throttling the amount of requests it receives from a client (ie your program) in a given amount of time.

Comment: I have set byte[102400], should it increase it??

Comment: google tends not to throttle much at all ... if you have enough bandwidth available to make a google endpoint worry you can run your own internet !!! The problem is that do loop.

Comment: Have you tried making bytesReceived smaller? 100M at once seems like a lot of data to me.

Comment: His buffer size is really down to his own ram availability ... that wouldn't cause request issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its because you've reached the end of the content and yet you are still requesting more ...

```
do
{
   bytes = socket.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
   sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes));
}
while (bytes > 0);
```

This assumes that as long as the last request returned more than 0 bytes theres more available, when in actual fact when a network stream reaches the end the chances are you'll fill some of your buffer on the last loop. (e.g. bytes > 0 but nothing more to get) ... so the server closes the connection.

try something like this instead ...

```
do
{
   bytes = socket.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
   sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes));
}
while (bytes == bytesReceived.Length);
```

Some servers (ask is probably one of them) obviously don't auto close the connection as you would expect hence the reason it won't always fail.

:::EDIT:::

My test sample:

Load visual studio, create a new console app then paste the following in to the generated program class (in place of all existing code):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string test = Get("http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=test&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a");
            Console.Read();
        }

        public static string Get(string url)
        {
            Uri requestedUri = new Uri(url);
            string fulladdress = requestedUri.Host;
            IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(fulladdress);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            try
            {
                using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP))
                {
                    socket.Connect(entry.AddressList[0], 80);

                    NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(socket);

                    string part_request = string.Empty;
                    string build_request = string.Empty;
                    if (jar.Count != 0)
                    {
                        part_request = "GET {0} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {1} \r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\nCookie: {2}\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
                        build_request = string.Format(part_request, requestedUri.PathAndQuery, requestedUri.Host, GetCookies(requestedUri));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        part_request = "GET {0} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {1} \r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
                        build_request = string.Format(part_request, requestedUri.PathAndQuery, requestedUri.Host);
                    }

                    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(build_request);
                    socket.Send(data, data.Length, 0);

                    byte[] bytesReceived = new byte[4096];
                    int bytes = 0;
                    string currentBatch = "";

                    do
                    {
                        bytes = socket.Receive(bytesReceived);
                        currentBatch = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
                        Console.Write(currentBatch);
                        sb.Append(currentBatch);
                    }
                    while (bytes == bytesReceived.Length);

                    List<String> CookieHeaders = new List<string>();
                    foreach (string header in sb.ToString().Split("\n\r".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                    {
                        if (header.StartsWith("Set-Cookie"))
                        {
                            CookieHeaders.Add(header.Replace("Set-Cookie: ", ""));
                        }
                    }

                    //this.AddCookies(CookieHeaders, requestedUri);

                    socket.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMessage = ex.Message;
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        static CookieContainer jar = new CookieContainer();

        public static string GetCookies(Uri _uri)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            CookieCollection collection = jar.GetCookies(_uri);

            if (collection.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (Cookie item in collection)
                {
                    sb.Append(item.Name + "=" + item.Value + ";");
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        }
    }
```

I reduced the buffer to ensure that it was filled more than once ... seems ok from my end
This post comes with the typical works on my pc garantee :)

Comment: Hmmm ... sample url ??? ... requesting the google homepage is working perfectly for me

Comment: Sample url: http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c%23+socket+error+code#q=c%23+socket+receive+hangs&hl=en&prmd=ivns&ei=5xgoTvW6EITqrQeYyvm8CQ&start=30&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=12ccb9d214cafeb1&biw=1280&bih=909

Comment: ooo strange ... it doesn't hang ... but it doesn't seem to give a full response (or at least one that i was expecting ) when linking to a search result page ... hmmmm ...

Comment: Ok fixed ... try that ... run it in the state its in above first then import to your app, the problem is not the streaming it's something to do with massive strings and the way that stringbuilder converts. (at least thats how it appears)

Answer (score 1):

Testing received bytes quantity should work *most of time*.

**However, what happens if the last chunk of data matches the buffer length?**

```
byte[] requestBuffer = new byte[100];
int bytesRead;
do
{
    bytesRead = socket.Receive(requestBuffer);
    //do something
}
while (bytes == bytesReceived.Length); // Pretend bytes = 100
```

In the example above, if `bytes == 100` the socket has no more content to receive.

I suggest using the `Socket.Available` property, to ensure the program stops reading when there is no more content available.

```
byte[] requestBuffer = new byte[100];
int bytesRead;
while (socket.Available > 0)    
{
    bytesRead = socket.Receive(requestBuffer);
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You're reading more content from the stream than you've been given.**

1. So, you open up a connection to Google and ask for the homepage.
2. Google will give you its homepage, say, 10KB in size.
3. You allocate a buffer 102400 bytes large (aka. 100KB large) - 10 times more than what you need.

Now, this is where the problem occurs.

1. You've been reading the homepage, a few bytes at a time and you've now hit the 10KB mark. Google has fed you the entire homepage, BUT you keep trying to read, trying to ask for more data! What happens is now you're just waiting for more data, more data that doesn't come! You just keep waiting forever until your timeout hits. But because you've specified (in your code) to receive until you've read 100KB, but are only given 10KB, you'll never get there and seem to hang in that loop!

The solution?

Check if you've received any bytes.

```
bytes = socket.Receive(...);
if (bytes == 0)
{
    // no more data, exit loop. you can `break;` or use a while loop, as demonstrated below
}
```

This could be how you implement it cleanly:

```
do
{
   bytes = socket.Receive(...);
   // Process your data
}
while (bytes > 0);
```

Comment: you/re right but the problem is here while (bytes > 0) ... adding another if statement wont change that.